# looping javascript actions along timeline

Tags: javascript, loops, timeline

I'm trying to loop some javascript actions along a timeline. It works only for the first post but doesn't work for the rest. Have a look at my code and help me point out what exactly i'm doing wrong. Thanks

Javascript

```
    var comment = $('#add-comment');
var comments = $('#comments');
for (var i = 0; i < comment.length; i++) {
    $(comments).hide();
        $(comment).click(function() {
    $(comments).slideToggle(500);
});
}
```

html

```
<input type="button" id="add-comment" Comment(s)">
<div id="comments">
<div id="other-comments">
<a href="#">
<img src="uploads/user/image">
<span class="full_name"><?=$rows['first_name']?> <?=$rows['last_name']?></span>
</a><br/>
<p><?=$rows['comment']?></p>
</div>
</div>
```

**Edited**

```
    var comment = $('#feeds li #add-comment');
var comments = $('#feeds li #comments');

$(comments).each(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});

$(comment).click(function() {
    $(comments).each(function() {
        $(this).slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```

I found out that a little omission of an html element prevented it from looping. Now that it is looping if i click on the add comment it drops down all of the comment divs. I don't want it that way. I want the add-comment button to open it's respective div alone and not the whole thing. What can be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like a slight syntax hiccup.

Give this **Jquery** a try:

```
var comment = $('#add-comment');
var comments = $('#comments');

for (var i = 0; i < comment.length; i++) {
    $(comments).hide();
}

$(comment).click(function() {
$(comments).slideToggle(500);
});
```

Comment: Why are you trying to make it loop? You could string $(comment).hide(); to a button click instead.

Comment: Your current loop will simply hide the comments div, then repeat from 0 to the no. of characters in the comment string.

Comment: I'm off now, but if that doesn't help make sure that the page is loading before the jQuery API and the Jquery code. And that the API code is loading before your jQuery code.

Comment: Pls have a look at this site just to have an insight on what I want to achieve with this loop - http://ilon.org.uk/assessment.php?user=shon